# After finishing programming a game, how to bind the assets in the executable and package it so that it can be distributed to others?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I programmed a game in c++ using the code::blocks ide with minGW compiler which runs fine from within the compiler. Now I need to package the game so that I can distribute it. After googling I found out that the executable is made in the debug/release folder of the project. After building the game using the compiler in release mode I can find the executable in the "release" folder of my project. But when I run the executable, it is not able to load any assets (like images) and terminates immediately. How can I bind the assets with the executable ?

Comment: Put them in your resource file. That way you don't have to have images along with your "release." `IDB_TILESET_0               BITMAP  "C:/PointlessPathImages/main_tileset_7.bmp" ` is an example,that goes in your `.rc` file, `IDB_TILESET_0` is a resource id.

Comment: I did not understand. What is the resource file? I already have a folder named resource which contains all assets.

Comment: I found this, maybe it will help. http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/windows/windows_tutorial_3.shtm

Answer (score 0):

Your executable needs to be able to find the resources for the game.

Lets say you have an image foo.png, and you load it with something like loadImage("foo.png"). This assumes, the executable is in the same directory as the image file.
By starting your exe in your Release folder, the program can no longer locate its assets. Just move the exe into the project root and try starting it from there.